# Ngrx splitter & delaying an event

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm new to Ngrx and rxjs, so sorry for asking such a basic question.

I know how to make a "splitter" in an effects class, e.g.:

```
@Effect() didSomething$: Observable<Action> = this.actions
    .ofType('doSomething')
    .flatMap(task => [
        { type: 'perform1', payload: task.payload },
        { type: 'perform2', payload: task.payload }
    ]);
```

The problem I run into is: I wish to delay the firing of the second task, say for 2 seconds.

I've tried replacing second array element with

```
Observable.of({ type: 'perform2', payload: task.payload }).delay(2000)
```

which understandably causes the complaint that **`Observable<Action>` is not of type `Action`**.

How would I make this work? I.e., dispatching a second event to the `didSomething$` stream after some time passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge` to combine two action observables and `flatMap` that observable into the action stream:

```
@Effect()
didSomething$: Observable<Action> = this.actions
  .ofType('doSomething')
  .flatMap(task => Observable.merge(
    Observable.of({ type: 'perform1', payload: task.payload }),
    Observable.of({ type: 'perform2', payload: task.payload }).delay(2000)
  ));
```

Comment: I knew it had to be with merge, but as it is all new to me I was using it wrongly. Thanks!